# ObservableArrayMap with Object as value not getting Observed on value change in editext

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have a model class

```
public class ScopeDefination extends BaseObservable {

String value;
String key;
boolean isPrivate;
String category;

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public ScopeDefination(String key, String value, boolean isPrivate) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
}

public ScopeDefination(String key, String value, boolean isPrivate, String category) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
    this.category = category;
}

@Bindable
public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;notifyPropertyChanged(developer.manish.publicprivatescopecategory.BR.key);
}

@Bindable
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
    notifyPropertyChanged(developer.manish.publicprivatescopecategory.BR.value);
}

public boolean isPrivate() {
    return isPrivate;
}

public void setPrivate(boolean aPrivate) {
    isPrivate = aPrivate;
}
```

}

and I am trying to use it in a class for data binding like this

```
  ScopeDefination scopeDefination1 = new ScopeDefination(Keys.ADDRESS_HOME,"Address", true, Keys.FINANCIAL_INFO);
        ScopeDefination scopeDefination2 = new ScopeDefination(Keys.NAME,"Name", true, Keys.FINANCIAL_INFO);

        ObservableArrayMap<String, Object> user = new ObservableArrayMap<>();
        user.put(Keys.ADDRESS_HOME, scopeDefination1);
        user.put(Keys.NAME, scopeDefination2);
 fragmentFirebaseBinderBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_firebase_binder, container, false);
        fragmentFirebaseBinderBinding.setUser(user);
```

My XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>

    <import type="developer.manish.publicprivatescopecategory.ScopeDefination" />

    <import type="android.databinding.ObservableMap" />

    <variable
        name="user"
        type="ObservableMap&lt;String, Object>" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="developer.manish.publicprivatescopecategory.FirebaseBinder">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text='@{((ScopeDefination)user["username"]).getValue()}'/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text='@{((ScopeDefination)user["address_home"]).getValue()}' />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text='@{((ScopeDefination)user["username"]).getValue()}' />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text='@{((ScopeDefination)user["address_home"]).getValue()}' />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am able to show data on UI but when I edit data in Editext the corresponding **text view is not getting updated**.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a **Two-Way Binding** which is slightly different than the normal Binding. See the [blog entry](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android/) from George Mount.

Basically, you'll need to edit your Binding expressions from

```
android:text='@{((ScopeDefination)user["username"]).getValue()}'
```

to

```
android:text='@={((ScopeDefination)user["username"]).value}'
```

Notice that there is an extra `=` between the `@` and the `{`. This will notify your model whenever the data in the `EditText` changed. Also, you cannot use methods in `Two-Way Binding`, but using `.value` will work. Thanks to @George Mount for pointing this out.

Comment: Error:(26, 27) No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@={((ScopeDefination)user["username"]).getValue()}').

Comment: Looks like a typo. Check for that.

Comment: just added an =, nothing else

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild/start your project? Dive into the docs if you want to know more about Two-Way Databinding.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.

****/ data binding error ****msg:The expression scopeDefinationUserS.getValue() cannot cannot be inverted: Method calls may not be used in two-way expressions

Comment: please share documentation link for two way binding.

Comment: Look into the blog entry from George Mount - he wrote the Data Binding library and explains its behaviour pretty well. The link is  in my answer. Also, you got a pretty clear error - you'll need to remove the method call to enable the wanted two-way DataBinding. I think you can create a custom Two-way Binding for this.

Comment: The answer is almost perfect. The two-way binding won't work with the method, but you should be able to bind to the property `android:text="@={{((ScopeDefination)user["username"]).value}"`